# Click on a button until it disappears in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, loops, click, casperjs

I have this sample of my code:

```
function clickOldShares() {
  console.log("Waiting for all shares");
  element = document.querySelector("#pagelet_scrolling_pager > div > div > a"); 
  return element;
 }      

  casper.thenOpen("https://www.facebook.com/shares/view?id=" + fb_objectID,function(){
    console.log("Open post with object-id");
  });

  casper.then(function(){
    element = this.evaluate(clickOldShares);
  });


  casper.wait(2000,function() {
    console.log('ELEMENT1: ' + element);
    element = this.evaluate(clickOldShares);

  });

  casper.wait(2000,function() {
    newelement = this.evaluate(clickOldShares);  
    console.log('ELEMENT2: ' + newelement);
  });

  casper.wait(2000,function() {
    newelement = this.evaluate(clickOldShares);  
    console.log('ELEMENT3: ' + newelement);

  });
```

I´m not understanding how can I transform this calls to `clickOldShares` in a loop using CasperJS because `casper.wait` is asynchronous. May I have some example of how to do this, please?

The page doesn't load all data in one time. It's necessary to click on the 'Older Shares' button until the data appears. And this can happen many times, depending the amount of data. So, I need to click as often as needed before capturing data.

Comment: Where does `clickOldShares` end? It looks like everything is inside it, which would be really wrong. Since you want to click something, have you tried using `casper.click`? If you do, then you don't need `casper.evaluate()` or `clickOldShares`.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't see it!

Comment: Yes, I tried casper.click() before this. But didn't work it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing's first, you can't use `clickOldShares` for anything as it is now. `casper.evaluate()` provides access to the DOM, but the passed in function is sandboxed and executed in the page context. All data must be explicitly passed in and out, and this has to be primitive. DOM elements are not primitive and cannot be passed out of the page context (`this.evaluate(clickOldShares)` will always return `null`). You will either have to call the click code inside of the page context.

---

You can wait for an element to appear with `waitForSelector`. You really don't need to iterate to wait for it.

```
var selector = "#pagelet_scrolling_pager > div > div > a";
casper.start()
    .thenOpen(url)
    .waitForSelector(selector, null, null, 15000); // max 15 seconds
    .then(function(){
        this.capture("screen1.png");
        this.click(selector);
    })
    .then(function(){
        this.capture("screen2.png");
    })
    .run();
```

The third argument for `waitForSelector` is the callback for when the timeout is reached, but the element is not found. The fourth argument is a custom timeout. The default timeout is set to 10 seconds.

---

It seems you need to click on a certain selector until it disappears. You can't use a loop for this, because the functions are asynchronous. You will have to use recursion like this:

```
var selector = "#pagelet_scrolling_pager > div > div > a";
var i = 0;
function step() {
    if (this.exists(selector)) {
        this.capture("screen"+(i++)+".png");
        this.click(selector);
        this.wait(2000, step);
    } else {
        this.capture("screen_final.png");
    }
}

casper.start()
    .thenOpen(url)
    .then(step)
    .then(function(){
        // TODO: do something else
    })
    .run()
```

Comment: This works! But just in the first time. My code already solves the problem for this scenario . I need to know how can I click, wait for the anchor, and click again until the anchor no longer appears.

Comment: Well, that's a completely different question. Please edit your question to add this clarification.

Comment: Ok! The page doesn't load all data in one time. It's necessary to click in the 'Older Shares' for the rest of the data appears. And this can happen many times, depending the amount of data. So, I need to click as often as needed before capturing data

Better now? I'm sorry for my terrible english.

Comment: But everything is asynchronous, so I don't know how to put this click in some kind of loop. I tried many things, but nothing works yet.

Comment: The second snippet in my answer directly addresses your question now.

Comment: Your second snippet is returning this for me:
`
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:552:26)`

Comment: It's PhantomJS instability. I ran again and now works! :P 

But I'm now I'm scared! 

The recursive solution give me some ideas to try out.

Thanks!

Comment: In the 'else' of 'step' function I need to make a scraper. But '__utils__.getElementsByXPath' is not working, probably because there is no reference to DOM there. Even with 'evaluate' I can use something like this:

`
function step() {
    if (this.exists(selector)) {
        
        this.wait(2000, step);
    } else {
        var elements = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('some/cool/xpath');
    }
}
`

There is something that I can do to save my scraper and have __utils__ there?

Comment: The clientutils (`__utils__`) is only available in the page context. Since you can't pass DOM nodes out of the page context, you will have to do everything inside. You can also use XPath helper in CasperJS outside of the page context to use XPaths in almost all CasperJS functions. `var x = require('casper').selectXPath;` and later `casper.echo(JSON.stringify(casper.getElementInfo(x('some/cool/xpath'), undefined, 4));`